# Finding solution in polar form, raised to a power

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

The problem asks, find an equation equal to:

```
 z^3 = ( 1 + sqrt(3)*i )   where i is the square root of negative one.
```

I tried approaching this problem first by finding the radius r, and the argument, pheta.
calculating gives:

```
r = 2

pheta = π/3
```

now using DeMoivre's Law, I said:

```
z = 2(cos(π/3) + i*sin(π/3))
```

therefore,

```
z^3 = 8(cos(π) + i*sin(π))
```

but none of the answers are similar to this?! what am i doing wrong?

in the answers, instead of having r = 8, they have that r= 2^1/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$z^3=2\cdot\text{cis}\left(2n\pi+\frac{\pi}3\right)=2\cdot\text{cis}\frac{\pi(6n+1)}3$$ where $n$ is any integer   and cis$(x)=\cos x+i\sin x$

$$\implies z=2^{\dfrac13}\cdot\text{cis}\frac{\pi(6n+1)}9$$ where $n\equiv0,1,2\pmod3$